# How can we to not uninitialized an non-nullable object for unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I'm trying to test that an error dialog appear when an exception is thrown. For that i want to emulate an UninitializedPropertyAcessException to test this piece of code :

```
try {
    account.solde?.let { view?.displaySolde(it) }
} catch (ex : Exception) {
    view?.displayErrorMessage()
}
```

And my test looks like this :

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    view = mock(AccountDetailActivity::class.java)

    presenter = AccountDetailPresenterImpl(
        mock(OperationServiceFactory::class.java),
        mock(StatisticsHelper::class.java)
    )

    presenter.view = view
}

@Test
fun testAccountIsNotInitialized() {
    presenter.account = null
    verify(view).displayErrorMessage()
}
```

But the parameter account can not be null or not initialized because it is a non-null type.

Have you a workaround to test that the error dialog is correctly shown ?

Thanks

Comment: why are you catching an exception that won't never been thrown ?

Comment: It is thrown sometimes, i don't know why, it crashed the app and now i just want to show a dialog to prevent crash

Comment: you don't know why it throws ?

Comment: I agree, you should rather investigate that exception. That is the point: you dont **ignore** bugs, you fix them.

Comment: I don't know why account property is not initialized sometimes.I'ma agree that i need to fix that, but for now i just need to prevent crash.